# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04098: trigger 'MYTABLE.MY_SEQUENCE_ID' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: oracle11g

I am creating this oracle 11g statement inside a java String and then executing it in sql developer. I tried running it on the database and got a warning when the trigger 
is created. But, when run from the code,  I get the error mentioned in my title.

Please tell me where is the mistake and how i can fix it ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myschema.my_sequence_id BEFORE INSERT ON myschema.mytable 
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT my_sequence_id.nextval INTO :new.mycolumn FROM DUAL; end; /
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a trigger named `my_sequence_id` if you already have a sequence `my_sequence_id`.  They share the same namespace.  Your trigger would need to be named something other than the name of the sequence (or any other object in the schema).

Comment: Hi Justin, sorry for the mess i created. I finally managed to fix it at this post - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192124/trigger-auto-num-gen-compiled-warning-execution-completed-with-warning

Thanks a million !